# vtkStandardNewMacro gives error C4430: missing type specifier

Tags: c++, vtk

I have the following code:

```
#include <vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h>

class InteractorStyle : public vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera
{
    public:
        static InteractorStyle* New() {};
        vtkTypeMacro(InteractorStyle, vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera);
        InteractorStyle() {
            cout << "test";
        }
        virtual void OnLeftButtonDown();

        virtual void OnKeyPress();

    private:

};
vtkStandardNewMacro(InteractorStyle); //error here

void InteractorStyle::OnLeftButtonDown()
{
    std::cout << "test";
    // Forward events
    vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::OnLeftButtonDown();
};
void InteractorStyle::OnKeyPress()
{
    // Get the keypress
    vtkRenderWindowInteractor *rwi = this->Interactor;
    std::string key = rwi->GetKeySym();

    // Output the key that was pressed
    std::cout << "Pressed " << key << std::endl;
    // Forward events
    vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::OnKeyPress();
};
```

Even though I follow the [tutorial](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/KeypressEvents), it always gives me below error for `vtkStandardNewMacro(InteractorStyle);` :

> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int

How to fix this?

Comment: this error might mean you are missing some headers.

Comment: @AMA Thanks.. I have to add `#include <vtkObjectFactory.h>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to add is `#include <vtkObjectFactory.h>`. The tutorial never explicitly mentioned this, too bad.